# Remote Enterprise Session Bean method return type

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb, javabeans

Currently in my project I've defined the Enterprise Session Bean and the interface. I'm trying to create a method that returns an class that I've defined. Currently that class in in in the same project as the Enterprise Session Bean. But I'm getting an error from the project where the interface is defined. Should I add the class that I want to return to the interface project, or is there any better way to do this?

Note: I'm working with netbeans

Comment: The error is from the interface, it can't find the class

Comment: can you tell me the exact error? have you done imports for the Class?

Comment: I found the solution, it seems that the class must be in the same project as the interface, and not in the same as the enterprise java bean. Thanks anyway.